# Whats this Photoshop filter name

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Could someone tell me what the name of the filter that extracts part of the image that is selected by a brush. What you do is go around the outline of an image with a brush and then fill it in and then click ok and it extracts the selected part of the image. people use it to go around a persons hair for example to take away the background.

Comment: You may like this sister site in beta status: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Extract filter was removed from CS5 and above. But you can now use the Refine Edge options to tweek your selection: get a selection tool and Right click > Refine Edge or click Refine Edge at the top bar or click on the menu Selection > Refine Edge. It's quite explanatory, 'cause it has some example images at the bottom when you hover over the sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean selection tool??? Like this :

[image]

and This is a `magnetic lasso tool`.